# \acro clickable links, sometimes works, sometimes not, despite same code

Tags: acronyms, hyperlink

I am struggling with `\acro` acronyms and hopefully one can help. I am using my uni template, based on the Springer Nature template.

I create my acronyms with `\acro`. This works well for most of them. However for three (see below) it doesn't create a link in the acronym list (see screenshot).
The first three links are compiled well and have a clickable link. The last three, revDSG, ISG and BÜPF, doesnt.

Any idea why? I hope I copied a working code example.
[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref} % Clickable links
\usepackage[printonlyused]{acronym} %Abbreviations

%\hypersetup{final}

\begin{document}
\begin{acronym}
%those work
\acro{DSG}{Datenschutzgesetz}
\acro{VDSG}{Verordnung zum Bundesgesetz über den Datenschutz}

% those throw an error about hyperlink not defined
\acro{revDSG}{revisioniertes Datenschutzgesetz}
\acro{ISG}{Informationssicherheitsgesetz}
\acro{BUePF}[BÜPF]{Bundesgesetz betreffend die Überwachung des Post- und Fernmeldeverkehrs}
\end{acronym}

Rechtlich
\begin{itemize}
\item \ac{revDSG}
\item \ac{ISG}
\item \ac{DSG}
\item \ac{VDSG}
\item \ac{BUePF}
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Crosspost: https://latex.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=5&t=34691

Comment: I cannot reproduce the issue with your code.

Comment: Thanks @egreg, now I am even more confused. Even deleting and rewriting doesnt help. Truly puzzled about it.

Comment: @Hachiman There must be something more; for instance, your image shows fonts that are different from the default you obtain with the example code.

Comment: @egreg, yes, I did change the font. But the thing is the acro works for most of them.
I define them all in the same way, like 
`\begin{acronym}

\acro{ISG}[ISG]{Informationssicherheitsgesetz}
\acro{revDSG}{revisioniertes Datenschutzgesetz}
\acro{BÜPF}{Bundesgesetz betreffend die Überwachung des Post- und Fernmeldeverkehrs}
\acro{EDÖB}{Eidgenössischer Datenschutz- und Öffentlichkeitsbeauftragter}
\acro{DSG}{Datenschutzgesetz}
\end{acronym}`
Then I write my text and use them. 
`Einen Auszug aus dem \ac{DSG} Art. 3 ist im Appendix gelistet \ref{app:defDSG}.`

Comment: Mh, hard to copy the code here. 

So for 95% defining an acronym with \acro{}{}, and then using it with \ac{} works. 
Exact same code, just a different acronym and it breaks the hyperlinks in the ToC